# get value from different activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, android-tabhost

Okay i have tabbed host activity that hosting 3 different activity. So in activity1 i have value of latitude and longitude that i get from GPS. so the question is how can i get that value in activity1 to be used in activity2 dynamically ? if i use intent then the value passed is just the last value from activity1. what i need is the activity1 is still running(in background) and capture the value from OnLocationChanged Method then send the value to the activity 2.

i made some of method in activity 1 and then creating another instance of activity1 but it doesn't works.

```
activty1 x = new activity1();
double lat = x.getLatitude();
```

Comment: You should not create an instance of Activity class. You can pass the values using intent. You can also use `startActivityForResult` Activity has a lifecycle and is started by `startActivity`

Comment: You can make a Handler which puts the values periodically in a sharedPreference and in your second activity make a Handler which periodically receives it.

Comment: Use a broadcastreceiver to handle the updates in the receiving activity, use intents to fire of new updates. Raghunandan proposed startActivityForResult. Broadcastreceiver would be a better way if you are handling perdiodiccaly events.

Comment: thanks everyone, i will study the sharedPreference and broadcastreceiver first

Answer (score 1):

You can create an activity passing it extras:

Int Act1

```
Intent i = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
i.putExtra("someData", 100);
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

In Act2

```
int x = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("someData");
x++;
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("someModifiedData", x);
setResult(ActivityInfo.DrawingABlank, i);
finish();
```

In Act1

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    int y = data.getExtras().getInt("someModifiedData");
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, but in act2 does it receive the value(getintent()) method  everytime the value changed ?

Comment: Only one activity can be in the foreground at a time. Every time the activity is recreated, the data will get updated. While Act2 is in the forground, Act1 will go into its onPause state, and halt until onActivityResult has been called. If you need to have a segment of code run, regardless of what is in the foreground, you might want to look into using a `Service`.

Comment: You should call `startActivityForResult` every time the value changes. Assuming the value is variable that should be passed to other activity by `putExtra`

Answer (score 0):

create two activity MainActivity , SecondActivity

in MainActivity :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("message","your text");

    startActivityForResult(intent,100);
```

```html
/// under onActivityResult

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == 100) {
    String message=data.getStringExtra("message2");
}
}
```

```html
SecondActivity:

 String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
 Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("message2","MESSAGE");
                setResult(SecondActivity.RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();
```